# How to use Offline GoogleMap Tiles in mapserver?

Tags: google-maps, wms, mapserver

I've downloaded GoogleMaps Tiles from zoom 9 to 16 in selected area with "Offline Map Maker". I want to add this Tiles to my map in MapServer.

How to do it?

Comment: Not sure if that is a legal move...

Comment: @mapBaker i want to use this map for offline usage. cann't use online api.

Comment: I'm sure that is also not legal according to their usage terms.